# KineticJS: make multiple clones be draggable as a Kinetic.Group

Tags: draggable, kineticjs

How to make clones be draggable as an entire group?

I have two layers: the first contains some items (kinetic images and rectangles), and the second is the drop zone. What I want to do is:

- drop the images inside the borders of the rectangle,
- then after dropping the items for the first time, and when I click on a rectangle, all the items are dragged with that rectangle in a `Kinetic.Group`, so apparently I'll have to make a hit test

It's something a little bit like this http://jsfiddle.net/7BkR7/1/ but with cloning the big rectangles.. I was inspired by this example but failed to adapt it to my solution. It's really not clear for me, I need advice and help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to clone a group and all its contained nodes:

```
layer.add( anyContainerGroup.clone({draggable:true} );
```

To make your draggable container groups, do the same thing you did with the small rects

- Make your blue, green & gold stroked containers un-draggable (they are "originals")
- Make a clone of each container placed directly on top of the original (the clones are draggable)
- When a small rect is dropped in the clone container, add the small rect to that clone container
- The clone containers (including any contained small rects) can be dragged to your dropzone.

Comment: Hi @markE , so this is what I've done so far http://jsfiddle.net/v778S/3/ . adding the lines of code that detect the rectangles on the layer and add to groups made some bugs, like changing the drop target, besides, it doesn't detect intersection. (see console)

Comment: I made it :) I just forgot to set width and height of the Kinetic.Group that I'm manipulating! Cheers!